# Excel formula to find duplicates from multiple sheets and list down on a new sheet or master sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates, distinct, worksheet

I have an excel workbook which stores Employee data. It has 3 sheet which has data coming from 3 different sources. All the 3 sheet has the Employee ID column as common which is ideally the first column.

Now I am looking for a formula which could find Employee ID which are present on all 3 sheets and list down in the master sheet in the same workbook preferably in Column1. I am not looking for Unique or Distinct Employee ID's but one's which are present on all these 3 sheets.

Compulsorily the Employee ID has to be on all the 3 sheets then only should appear in the Master sheet. How can i achieve that?

[image: Sample]

Every time I manually copy paste the employee ids in Master sheet and then do a vlookup on all 3 sheet and then i extract the one's which appear on all the 3 sheets and delete the rest. This take sometime. Now I am looking for formula which can do that for me. Compare, search and then list down.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A1</kbd> --> **Method 1**

```
=LET(
     _Stores, TOCOL('*'!A:A,1),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(_Stores),
     _Counts, MMULT(N(_Uniq=TOROW(_Stores)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(_Stores))^0),
     SORT(FILTER(_Uniq,_Counts=3)))
```

---

Or, If applicable can use `GROUPBY()` --> Exclusively Applicable `MS365` Office Insiders Version. **Method 2**:

```
=LET(
     _Stores, TOCOL('*'!A:A,1),
     _Group, GROUPBY(_Stores,_Stores,ROWS,,0,1),
     TAKE(FILTER(_Group, TAKE(_Group,,-1)=3),,1))
```

---

**Note:** When placing the formula in the cell the `*` in `TOCOL()` function will automatically change to `TOCOL(Sheet1:Sheet3!A:A,1)`

---

Or, Can use `BYROW()` function - **Method 3**:

```
=LET(
     _Stores, TOCOL(Sheet1:Sheet3!A:A,1),
     _Uniq, SORT(UNIQUE(_Stores)),
     FILTER(_Uniq, BYROW(_Uniq, LAMBDA(x, SUM(--(x=_Stores))))>=3))
```

---

**Explanations about the formula logic:**

- The above formulas are dynamic array formulas which uses firstly the `LET()` function, helps in eliminating redundant calculations, avoids using repeated formulas/ranges and improves working functionalities of Excel by performance.
- `_Stores` variable is the source ranges from all the three sheets, in the example it uses `TOCOL()` function with an optional argument `[ignore]` --> `1 - ignore blanks` as we are taking the whole column `A:A` from all the sheets, we are excluding the empty cells if any. This stacks one upon the other into a single array.
- Next, using `UNIQUE()` function, extracting each unique values.
- `_Counts` variable uses an `MMULT()` function which does a matrix product of two arrays. The output is an array of counts.
- Finally, using `FILTER()` function to `include` those which have counts equal to `3` and lastly using `SORT()` function to return an `A-Z` sorted data.

The algorithm remains same for the other two following formulas provided, the second uses a `GROUPBY()` function which is `Beta`/`Office Insider` Version, one needs to enable it while using `MS365` and writing the above, it is bit shorter, and the last method uses a `LAMBDA()` helper function called `BYROW()` which does custom logical calculations per row in an array and returns one result per row as an array.

The basic logic remains same, stack all the data into one, then get the uniques, do the counts and keep only those which are all present in the three stores.

---

This can also be accomplished using `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)`

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a tables and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`, `Table2` and `Table3`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each not Text.StartsWith([Name], "Query")),
    #"Expanded Content" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Content", {"Column1"}, {"Column1"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Expanded Content",{"Column1"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Other Columns", {"Column1"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each [Count] = 3),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows1",{{"Column1", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Count"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

**Notes:** The second step in the `Power Query`, I am only taking the tables from the three sheets and not the table which will be an output in the Master Sheet, hence excluding it or filtering it out. So, when you name the `Tables` and while pasting the `M-Code` do exclude output query, otherwise whenever you add new data and refresh the imported table in the `Master Sheet` it will keep duplicating the desired output.

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each not Text.StartsWith([Name], "Query"))
```

---

However, in the above formulas if you don't have access to `TOCOL()` function then you can replace that part with the following, but it has a drawback, since it uses `FILTERXML()` and `TEXTJOIN()`, the former will not work on web version of `Excel` if you happen to use it, and the later has character limitations -->`32767 characters (cell limit)` which when reached will return `#VALUE!` error, but with the existing example it works without any issue.

---

```
=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",,Sheet1:Sheet3!A:A),",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b")
```

---

Comment: Thank you very much for the Awesome methods Mayukh. Method 1 worked completely perfect!! You are a saviour!! Thanks very much!!